# No option to submit latest build for review in App Store connect

Tags: ios

I have a new version that is available on testflight (1.2) that says it is ready to submit for review. But, when I go to the App Store tab there is no option to submit a new build as usual.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voNCL.jpg)

Comment: You need to tap the blue + to create a version 1.2 entry for ios

Comment: Hi User, based on what you showed in the picture, you have an active iOS app v1.0 active in the App Store. You added a tvOS app to the Xcode project, that already contains the active iOS app. Is that correct? When so, I think you need to make a new version of both apps.

Answer (score 1):

You can click on the **blue (+) button** next to "iOS App" to create a new version and then assign the build that was submitted to TestFlight.

[image: App Store Connect - add new version]

Comment: I don't see the option. I submitted an old version with feedback and now my app shows "Ready for Review" but I can't submit anything.